# React native face detection not working for me (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, face-detection

I am trying to build a face detection module in objective-c using react native. I am using [onFacesdetected](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md#onfacesdetected) from react native. But it is not working for me.
Below is the code :

```
<RNCamera
        ref={ref => {
          this.camera = ref;
        }}
        style = {styles.preview}
        type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
        flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
        faceDetectionMode={RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.fast}
        onFacesDetected={(d)=>{console.log('onFacesDetected',d);}}
        permissionDialogTitle={'Permission to use camera'}
        permissionDialogMessage={'We need your permission to use your camera phone'}
        onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
          console.log(barcodes)
        }}
    />
```

When the camera opens for the first time it prints **'onFacesDetected', { type: 'face', faces: [], target: 27 }** after that upon bringing the face in front of camera it does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue we have to change in library code in RNCameraUtils.m file.

[Ref of error fix](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2349)

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS 12 broke it. Looking at their current issues. There is fixes including setting legacy build system. however some people reported that broken. Is it working on android?

Comment: This is a comment on the original question and not an answer, you should put it in the appropriate place, or provide code examples on how this can be resolved. Perhaps also link your reference to "current issues" and "some people reported"